# How to process each row/buffer synchronously when reading a file asynchronously using a stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, stream, fs

as you can see i have a js that takes a .csv and calls an async function for every row (4 different functions iteratively).

The problem is that I need to **wait the end of the function in the i-th iteration before I proceed to the i+1 iteration**.

```
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');

var i=1;

fs.createReadStream('table.csv')
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', (row) => {
      switch(i%4){
          case 1: org1createPatient(row.patientId, row.FirstName, row.LastName, row.Age, row.Sex, row.ChestPainType, row.RestingBP, row.Cholesterol, row.FastingBS, row.RestingECG, row.MaxHR, row.ExerciseAngina, row.Oldpeak, row.ST_Slope, row.HeartDisease); break;
          case 2: org2createPatient(row.patientId, row.FirstName, row.LastName, row.Age, row.Sex, row.ChestPainType, row.RestingBP, row.Cholesterol, row.FastingBS, row.RestingECG, row.MaxHR, row.ExerciseAngina, row.Oldpeak, row.ST_Slope, row.HeartDisease); break;
          case 3: org3createPatient(row.patientId, row.FirstName, row.LastName, row.Age, row.Sex, row.ChestPainType, row.RestingBP, row.Cholesterol, row.FastingBS, row.RestingECG, row.MaxHR, row.ExerciseAngina, row.Oldpeak, row.ST_Slope, row.HeartDisease); break;
          case 0: org4createPatient(row.patientId, row.FirstName, row.LastName, row.Age, row.Sex, row.ChestPainType, row.RestingBP, row.Cholesterol, row.FastingBS, row.RestingECG, row.MaxHR, row.ExerciseAngina, row.Oldpeak, row.ST_Slope, row.HeartDisease); break;
      }
    i++;
  })
  .on('end', () => {
    console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
  });





  async function org1createPatient(patientId, FirstName, LastName, Age, Sex, ChestPainType, RestingBP, Cholesterol, FastingBS, RestingECG, MaxHR, ExerciseAngina, Oldpeak, ST_Slope, HeartDisease) {
    ...
  }

  async function org2createPatient( patientId, FirstName, LastName, Age, Sex, ChestPainType, RestingBP, Cholesterol, FastingBS, RestingECG, MaxHR, ExerciseAngina, Oldpeak, ST_Slope, HeartDisease) {
    ...
  }

  async function org3createPatient( patientId, FirstName, LastName, Age, Sex, ChestPainType, RestingBP, Cholesterol, FastingBS, RestingECG, MaxHR, ExerciseAngina, Oldpeak, ST_Slope, HeartDisease) {
   ...
  }

  async function org4createPatient( patientId, FirstName, LastName, Age, Sex, ChestPainType, RestingBP, Cholesterol, FastingBS, RestingECG, MaxHR, ExerciseAngina, Oldpeak, ST_Slope, HeartDisease) {
   ...
  }
```

How can I get what I want?
Hope my question is clear enough!

Comment: `await` all of the `org[n]createPatient` functions and use async for the arrow function (`(row) => {`).

Comment: I think you need to queue the rows into an array or a hash, and then run an asynchronous busy-wait loop until you get all the results you expect... Maybe there's a better way, which is why I'm not submitting this as an answer

Comment: `var orgCreate = [org4createPatient, org1createPatient, org2createPatient, org3createPatient]; await orgCreate[i%4](row.patientId, row.FirstName, row.LastName, row.Age, row.Sex, row.ChestPainType, row.RestingBP, row.Cholesterol, row.FastingBS, row.RestingECG, row.MaxHR, row.ExerciseAngina, row.Oldpeak, row.ST_Slope, row.HeartDisease);`

Comment: Awaiting inside the callback function is not sufficient, as `.on(event, callback)` never calls `callback` synchronously. The stream always keeps running in parallel independently from any callback. See refer to the answer below for the full explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `readStream` you are using here is asynchronous, meaning `.on(event, callback)` will trigger every time a new piece of data is read, independently of any `callback` triggered. In other words, the execution of the `callback` function here does not impact this process, it will be ran in parallel, every time `event` received.

This means that in case `callback` was to execute a piece of code that is asynchronous, you may very well end up in a situation where multiple instances of this function may still be running by the time the next read `event` is received.

> Note: this holds true for any event, including the `'end'` event.

If you were to use `async/await` on `callback` if would only make the internal logic of this function synchronous. It would still not impact the rate at which your data is read.

In order to do so you will want to use both `async/await` on `callback` (to make it internally synchronous) and have `callback` manually pause and resume the read operation happening in parallel.

```js
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');

let i = 1;

const stream = fs.createReadStream('table.csv').pipe(csv());

stream.on('data', async (row) => {
   // pause overall stream until this row is processed
   stream.pause();

   // process row
   switch (i%4){
      case 1: await org1createPatient(row.patientId, row.FirstName, row.LastName, row.Age, row.Sex, row.ChestPainType, row.RestingBP, row.Cholesterol, row.FastingBS, row.RestingECG, row.MaxHR, row.ExerciseAngina, row.Oldpeak, row.ST_Slope, row.HeartDisease); break;
      case 2: await org2createPatient(row.patientId, row.FirstName, row.LastName, row.Age, row.Sex, row.ChestPainType, row.RestingBP, row.Cholesterol, row.FastingBS, row.RestingECG, row.MaxHR, row.ExerciseAngina, row.Oldpeak, row.ST_Slope, row.HeartDisease); break;
      case 3: await org3createPatient(row.patientId, row.FirstName, row.LastName, row.Age, row.Sex, row.ChestPainType, row.RestingBP, row.Cholesterol, row.FastingBS, row.RestingECG, row.MaxHR, row.ExerciseAngina, row.Oldpeak, row.ST_Slope, row.HeartDisease); break;
      case 0: await org4createPatient(row.patientId, row.FirstName, row.LastName, row.Age, row.Sex, row.ChestPainType, row.RestingBP, row.Cholesterol, row.FastingBS, row.RestingECG, row.MaxHR, row.ExerciseAngina, row.Oldpeak, row.ST_Slope, row.HeartDisease); break;
   }
   i++;

   // resume overall stream
   stream.resume();
});

stream.on('end', () => {
  // now guaranteed that no instances of `callback` is still running in parallel when this event is fired
  console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
});
```

Comment: Also note: You may have heard of `fs.readFileSync()` as another option to avoid having to deal with async streams of data. I would not recommend it as it would essentially read & cache the entire file at once (synchronously) before allowing you to process it. This is a lot heavier on memory than the solution presented above, which will only cache and process one row at a time, especially if you are dealing with larger files.

Answer (score 1):

Solution below is using [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops) library, which is very efficient in this case, because `pipe(csv())` returns an `AsyncIterable`, so it should be processed accordingly.

Since you do not care about what those processing functions return, we can just [throttle](https://vitaly-t.github.io/iter-ops/index.html#throttle) the processing for each row:

```js
const {pipe, throttle, onEnd, catchError} = require('iter-ops');
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');

const asyncIterable = fs.createReadStream('table.csv').pipe(csv());

const i = pipe(
    asyncIterable,
    throttle(async (row, index) => {
        switch (index % 4) {
            case 1: await org1createPatient(row.patientId, ...); break;
            case 2: await org2createPatient(row.patientId, ...); break;
            case 3: await org3createPatient(row.patientId, ...); break;
            case 0: await org4createPatient(row.patientId, ...); break;
            default: break;
        }
    }),
    onEnd(s => {
        console.log(`Completed ${s.count} rows, in ${s.duration}ms`);
    }),
    catchError((err, ctx) => {
        console.log(`Failed on row with index ${ctx.index}:`, err);
        throw err; // to stop the iteration
    })
);

async function processCSV() {
    // this will trigger the iteration:
    for await(const a of i) {
        // iterate and process the CSV
    }
}
```

P.S. I'm the author of [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops).